Runtime Error 217 0040A300 installing Astrometrica Software on Windows 11
I'm trying to install Astrometrica software on Windows 11, but I keep encountering a "Runtime Error 217 0040A300" message. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Details:

OS: Windows 11
RAM: 4GB
Software: Astrometrica Installer (1.4)
Error Message: Runtime Error 217 0040A300

I've tried:

Reinstalling the software after a complete uninstall


Press the Windows key + R shortcut (or go to Start and search for "Run").
In the Run dialog box, type %LOCALAPPDATA% (including the percent signs) and click OK.

That should open the current user's AppData\Local folder. Astrometrica requires a folder named "Astrometrica" to be present here. If you don't see it, simply create a new folder and name it "Astrometrica".
Source: http://iasc.cosmosearch.org/Home/FAQ/
(FAQ > Astrometrica Questions > Astrometrica encounters a Runtime Error when opening. How do I fix this?)
